# Rails decimal pricing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails app allows users to add the price of their item; it's in the model. However, for example if I say I want to sell something for $25, Rails renders it as $25.0. That just isn't standard -- it should be $25.00. Or if the user prices something at $120, it should display as $120.00. Here's the migration that I originally did:

```
class AddDecimalPriceToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :decimal_price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
  end
end
```

Should I change the scale or precision to do what I'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, decimal is fine - instead, what you want to do in the frontend is use the helper `number_to_currency(@product.decimal_price, precision: 2)`